# Why lsof shows odd sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, unix

I am opening a unix domain socket on file system. `lsof` give me this as the output.

```
proxyShel 27379      root    0u     unix 0xe8250200      0t0   26605515 /var/lib/dsock
proxyShel 27379      root    2u     unix 0xe74e4600      0t0   26606355 socket
```

Well, "dsock" is the socket I am listening to, but what does the second entry mean? :s

Comment: Does that imply that when your `dsock` is not open, the other socket doesn't appear in `lsof`?

Comment: Yes. I have noticed the problem arises randomly after accept of a connection.... which leads me to assume that is *may* be due fd is not closed. I am unable to trace it out in the source at the moment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra socket is opened by syslog to syslogd.

cheers!